# How to show a message only on first visit with Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular8 and I need to show the message in HTML but only on the first visit on this page. And after when I back on this page this message is hidden. How to make it?

Comment: you can use localStorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use localStorage as

```
constructor(){
  this.firsttime = localStorage.getItem('firsttime');

  if(localStorage.getItem('firsttime') == null || localStorage.getItem('firsttime') == undefined) {
        this.firsttime = 'true';
        localStorage.setItem('firsttime', 'true');
      }
      else localStorage.setItem('firsttime', 'false');
  }
```

Demo code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firsttime1

Comment: You already have the value, no need to call `localStorage.getItem` again. Also unless you explicitly want to use type coercion you should always compare using `===` and not `==`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This code is working fine, but to see the message I need to refresh the page. But I need to see the text right away, when open the page first time (without refreshing).

Comment: I add inside if this.firsttime ='true' you can check it

Answer (score 0):

Hie Helen , You can show that message using your cookie service or local-storage or via database , you can check using condition if the cookie for that particular is saved or not , if not you can show the message or if the cookie is saved you can make it hidden